# Store json data in a variable inside a proxy pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
var my = {};

(function () { 
    var self = this;
    this.sampleData = { };

    this.loadData = function() {
       $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?', 
          {tags: "cat", tagmode: "any", format: "json"},
          function(data){
             self.sampleData = data;
          }
       );
    };
}).apply(my);

my.loadData();
console.log(my.sampleData); // {}
```

The problem is my.sampleData not have anything.

Try this sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/r57ML/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `getJSON` call is **asynchronous**, so you're looking for the data before it's been returned. Instead, put your code using the data *inside* the callback, either directly or indirectly.

For instance, you can have your `loadData` call accept a callback:

```
var my = {};

(function () { 
    var self = this;
    this.sampleData = { };

    this.loadData = function(callback) {
       $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?', 
          {tags: "cat", tagmode: "any", format: "json"},
          function(data){
             self.sampleData = data;
             callback(); // <==== Call the callback
          }
       );
    };
}).apply(my);

my.loadData(function() { // <=== Pass in a callback
    console.log(my.sampleData); // Now the data is htere
});
```

---

Side note: Since your `my` object is a singleton, you can simplify that code a fair bit, no need for `apply`, `this`, or `self`, since your anonymous function is a closure over the context in which `my` is defined:

```
var my = {};

(function () { 
    my.sampleData = { };

    my.loadData = function(callback) {
       $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?', 
          {tags: "cat", tagmode: "any", format: "json"},
          function(data){
             my.sampleData = data;
             callback();
          }
       );
    };
})();

my.loadData(function() {
    console.log(my.sampleData); // Now the data is htere
});
```

Of course, if you're using a constructor function or something instead (you weren't in your quoted code, but...), then of course you might need the more complex structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () { 
        var self = this;
        this.sampleData = {};

        this.loadData = function() {
           $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?', 
              {tags: "cat", tagmode: "any", format: "json"},
              function(data){
                 self.sampleData = data;
                 console.log(my.sampleData); // you get sample data after ajax response
              },
           'json');
        };
    }).apply(my);

    my.loadData();
```